# What is the correct tense to use after "based on which"

Tags: verb-forms, syntax, to-infinitive

> The objective of the project was to provide the Government with the required ground conditions and climate information, **based on which** *to make* informed investment decisions for future expansion of road infrastructures.

After **based on which**, is it correct to use *to make*?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "Informed investment decisions ..." expresses a desired consequence of "provide the Government with the required ground conditions...".

Expressing of a desired consequence calls for *would*.  I believe technically this is conditional mood, tense, etc.

> The objective of the project was to provide the Government with the required ground conditions and climate information, based on which *[ the Government | it ] would make* informed investment decisions for future expansion of road infrastructures.
>
> Another simpler example: I would like to build my house once the trees are cut down.

Comment: Thank you! if I don't use [ the Government | it ], what is the possible way to express it?  for example, "...required ground conditions and climate information, to make informed investment decisions for future expansion of road infrastructures" is correct?

Comment: *Which* begins a new clause so you need to start the S-V-O pattern again.  So you need to specify the subject.  Even though it's the same.  There is too much distance between the beginnings of the clauses to get away with omitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Untangling that second clause a bit, you end up with

> [the Government] will make informed investment decisions based on [this information].

That seems perfectly sensible to me. The usage of make is backed up [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6431/what-is-the-difference-between-make-decision-and-take-decision).

The ugly "based on which" is an attempt to avoid a sentence that ends with a preposition, like this:

> provide the government with information that decisions can be based on.

[Winston Churchill](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/churchill.html) made fun of these overly rule-based re-arrangements.

Comment: Thank you! So, "To make" is not correct in my example, right? and based on your comment, can I express it as "The objective of the project was to provide the Government with the required ground conditions and climate information that informed investment decisions for future expansion of road infrastructures can be based on" ?

Comment: In the original sentence, you could change "to make" to "can be made" and move it to the end of the sentence. I think that your improved version is a lot more readable, though. What do you think?

Comment: "can be based on" comes very late at the end, so i'd say it as: The objective of the project was to provide the Government with the required ground conditions and climate information, based on which informed investment decisions can be made for future expansion of road infrastructures. What do you think?

Comment: "The objective of the project was to provide the Government with [the required] ground conditions and climate information as a basis for informed investment decisions on future expansion of road infrastructure."  Note: for->on and infrastructure is singular. My final offer.